# Crop left side of image

Tags: c#, image, crop, system.drawing

What i need to do is just crop following image

[image]

and display only the mail item instead of with that mail picture .

I have used the following code but it just crop the right side not left .

Note: Picture is just an example get it from google image

```
 Bitmap croppedBitmap = new Bitmap("E:/my234.png");
        try
        {
            croppedBitmap = croppedBitmap.Clone(new Rectangle(0,0,202, 17), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);
            pictureBox1.Image = croppedBitmap;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { string se = ex.ToString(); }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you read [MSDN?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944.aspx)

It's clearly stated that:

> rect
>
> Type: System.Drawing.Rectangle
>
> Defines the portion of this Bitmap to copy. ***Coordinates are relative
>   to this Bitmap***.

All you need are proper coordinates:

```
Rectangle(20, 0, 182, 17)
```

[image]